# Haskell : how to return from ( func :: IO a ) to main::IO

Tags: haskell

I have the following defined that displays a menu and would like 'r' to return to main :: IO.

displayMenu is of type IO BaseProduct and main of type IO so cannot have

"r" -> do
return main

```
 displayMenu :: IO BaseProduct
 displayMenu = do
  putStrLn "\n--- Choose and Item ---"
  putStrLn "1 - Basic\n2 - Super\n3 - Supreme\n4 - SoftDrink\n5 - Breadsticks\nr - Return"
  line <- getLine
  case line of
    "1" -> do
      return basicPizza
    "2" -> do
      return superPizza
    "r" -> do
      return ???
```

Also : is the rest of my code for displayMenu fine?
note - first  app I am writing based on  alvin alexanders post
[Pizza Store](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/haskell/example-haskell-application-pizza-point-sales-order-system/)

[image]

Comment: When you wrote `displayMenu :: IO BaseProduct`, you promised that `displayMenu` might do some IO but will definitely contain a `BaseProduct`. Returning to `main` does not result in a `BasProduct`, so the type system prevented you from doing so and catched the bug before you could implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function cannot choose a function it's returning *to*. Whoever calls `displayMenu` will regain the flow after it returns. I think, what you mean, is how to tell apart a choice of a product (has value) from a `Return` menu choice (no value). One way to do that is with `Maybe` type:

```
displayMenu :: IO (Maybe BaseProduct)
displayMenu = do
  putStrLn "\n--- Choose and Item ---"
  putStrLn "1 - Basic\n2 - Super\n3 - Supreme\n4 - SoftDrink\n5 - Breadsticks\nr - Return"
  line <- getLine
  case line of
    "1" -> do
      return $ Just basicPizza
    "2" -> do
      return $ Just superPizza
    "r" -> do
      return Nothing
```

Alternatively (and I would prefer that way), you can create a custom type for the menu action:

```
data MenuAction = Choice BaseProduct | Back

displayMenu :: IO MenuAction
displayMenu = do
  putStrLn "\n--- Choose and Item ---"
  putStrLn "1 - Basic\n2 - Super\n3 - Supreme\n4 - SoftDrink\n5 - Breadsticks\nr - Return"
  line <- getLine
  case line of
    "1" -> do
      return $ Choice basicPizza
    "2" -> do
      return $ Choice superPizza
    "r" -> do
      return Back
```

In both cases, the caller should be changed to handle the result accordingly.

Comment: choosing to implement a custom type for the menu action as explained - displayMenu will do some IO but will definitely contain  BaseProduct or Back (Micha Wiedenmann comment) So from what I understand I still cannot return to main..

Comment: @hoosain.madhi you don't return _to_, you return _from_ a function. If `main` is what's calling the function `displayMenu`, it will return to `main`, if not - it won't.